# MATLAB calculation on specific interval, shifted across data.

Tags: matlab

So, I'm working with a spread sheet in which each row has four important columns: x position (0-7000 units), y position (0-7000 units), theta angle (0-90), and phi angle (0-360). I have written the script I need to convert the theta and phi into Cartesian coordinates, then to calculate the eigenvalues for the entire data set as a whole, with no relation to position.

Now, what I'd like to do, is take a section, say 200 units wide, starting at the left of the (x,y) spread, and do the same calculation for all the data that falls into that area (x = 0 to 200), and record the eigenvalues at the center of that section (x=100), then shift the area say, 20 units to the right and repeat, and so on until the 200 unit wide area has shifted entirely across the 7000 unit spread.

Basically, I'm looking to do a sort of moving average where the eigenvalue calculation is my filter, and the width of the area of interest determines the degree of smoothing. I just haven't figured out how to write a loop that advances the 200 unit wide area of interest and can spit out a value at the center of it's current location.

I can supply the code I have to calculate Cartesian components and eigenvalues, although I don't think it's very relevant to what I'm trying to do. This mostly seems to be an issue of having no idea what to search for on the interwebs, so if someone can even point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is a rather straightforward [`for`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Oh, just that I'm not very good at any of this. I'm not really sure how to set up the 200 unit wide section to "scan" across the data in 20 unit increments and have it give me a usable output (eigenvalues for that interval with a corresponding, centered, x value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below code segment will give you an idea.

```
clc; clear all;

in = rand(20,1); % assume a 20*1 matrix

w = 5; % range from middle
j = 2; % jump

for i = 1+w:j:size(in,1)-w
    in(i,2) = mean(in(i-w:i+w,1));
    fprintf('\ni = %d\trange = %d:%d\tavg = %f', i, i-w, i+w, in(i,2));
end
```

Following is the output.

```
i = 6   range = 1:11    avg = 0.528908
i = 8   range = 3:13    avg = 0.501255
i = 10  range = 5:15    avg = 0.531217
i = 12  range = 7:17    avg = 0.557450
i = 14  range = 9:19    avg = 0.570374
```

Comment: This helps a ton! Fantastic!